# Django MultiValueDictKeyError handling media

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django application in which i must store uploaded media to root/media and am getting the following error:

```
'media'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
Django Version: 3.2.6
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

views.py code:

```
def home(request):
    form = PostForm()
    signupform=SignupModelForm()
    comments=CommentForm()

    post=Post.objects.all()
    commentall=Comments.objects.all()
    member = Member.objects.all()
    user = User.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        comments=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and request.POST['action']=='posting':

            
            data=form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.media = request.POST['media']
            
            data.save()
            print("posted status")
            return redirect("/home")
```

home.html code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="float:left; width:100%; margin-left: -10%;">
    
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    
    <button type="submit"  name="action" value="posting">Post</button>
    
   </form>
```

Thank you!

*edit*
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, ViewDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UsernameField
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput
from .models import *

User = get_user_model()
username=forms.CharField(max_length=50,help_text=None,required=True)
class SignupModelForm(UserCreationForm):
   
    username= forms.CharField(required=True,label_suffix=None )

    class Meta:
        
        model = User
        fields = (
        'first_name', 
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'user_type'
            )
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    media= forms.ImageField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        
        model = Post
        fields=(
            'content',
            'media',
        )
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content= forms.CharField(label="")
    class Meta:

        model = Comments
        fields=(
            'content',
        )
```

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import SET_NULL
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.enums import Choices
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel
class User(AbstractUser):
    about = models.CharField(default="Write a little bit about yourself.",max_length=100000)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="first name")
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="last name")
    user_types=(
        ('creator','creator'),
        ('viewer','viewer')
    )
    user_type= models.CharField(choices=user_types,default='---',max_length=25)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_online =models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False)
    pic=models.ImageField(default="https://moonvillageassociation.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/default-profile-picture1.jpg")
    pass
class Member(models.Model):
    User.first_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="first name")
    User.last_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="last name")
    user_types=(
        ('creator','creator'),
        ('viewer','viewer'),
        ('admin','admin')
    )

    about = models.CharField(default="Write a little bit about yourself.",max_length=100000)
    user_type= models.CharField(choices=user_types,default='---',max_length=25)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=SET_NULL,null=True)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verfication = models.ImageField()
    pic=models.ImageField(default="https://moonvillageassociation.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/default-profile-picture1.jpg")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}" 
class Post(models.Model):

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="")
    media = models.ImageField(default="")
    member = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}"
class Comments(models.Model):
    post= models.ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    member = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(default=None,max_length=1000,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
                return f"{self.post}"
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    request_from = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="to")
    request_to = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="from+")

class FriendsList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="user")
    friend = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="buddy")
    types=(
        ("follower","follower"),
        ("friend","friend"),
    )
    type= models.CharField(choices=types,default='---',max_length=25)
class Blocked(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="user_blocking")
    blocked = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="blocked_member")

class Events(models.Model):
    user_created=models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="user_created")
    event = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    follower_actions=(
        ("attending","attending"),
        ("not attending","not attending"),
        ("interested","interested"),
    )
    event_actions= models.CharField(choices=follower_actions,default='---',max_length=25)
class Messages(TimeStampedModel):
        message_from=models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="message_from")
        message_to=models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="message_to")
        message_content = models.CharField(null=False,default="",max_length=100000)
class Notification(TimeStampedModel):
        sender=models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="send")
        reciever=models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="recieve")
        content = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,related_name="notification_content")
```

and settings

```
"""
Django settings for dripchat project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-%&+0&x5hlvb+&#d%_vfb_-t!lz+1vwlm&^r925#dm^cn$=aznl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*','192.168.0.7']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'schedule',
    'djangobower',
    'feed',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dripchat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR /"templates","dripchat/templates","feed/templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.template.context_processors.request",

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dripchat.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'feed.User'
#change console to smtp
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/landing"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/home"
STATICFILES_FINDERS=[
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',

]
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui',
    'bootstrap'
)

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL/ 'components/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'feed.User'
```

I may have done settings.py wrong but, it seems to be in saving the form data as it is not being saved to media/ either

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /home
'media'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 
'media'
Exception Location:

Comment: use `request.POST.get('media')` instead of `request.POST['media']`. `request.POST` is a dictionary-like object so use `.get` method to avoid `KeyError`